# How can I mock an API Gateway RestAPI endpoint and return within response a custom variable based on request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Id like to mock an API Gateway RestAPI action within just the gateway itself (Mock type), and I'd like to execute code that observes the request body and copies values from the request and places them in response.

How can I accomplish this without having the RestAPI targeting an actual backend api?

Is this possible using the mock alone? Or do I need to actually create a backend api and only can mock it that way?

Answer (score 0):

[Mock API Gateway responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-mock-integration.html) are generally for demonstrating an example of how a response might look, you can do some minor checks but probably not enough for what you are trying to achieve.

If you're trying to return a response based on some specified content the best approach would be have a resource invoke a Lambda function that can process whatever is needed to be fetched from the response then return a template response containing the data you have extracted from it.